Grafana + Prometheus don't show data from the previous day
Every morning I see the same problem. Graphs of CPU, Disk and Memory of Kubernetes nodes start from 6 AM/8:30 AM but I can't see previous data.
Graphs of CPU, Disk and Memory of Kubernetes nodes start from 6 AM/8:30 AM but I can't see previous data.
I create the environment with Terraform and Helm.
This is my configuration for prometheus-values.yaml:
prometheus:
    serviceMonitorSelector: {}
    podMonitorSelector: {}
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: node
        relabel_configs:
          - action: labelmap
            regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
          - target_label: __address__
            replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
            regex: (.+)
            target_label: __metrics_path__
            replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: pod
        relabel_configs:
          - action: labelmap
            regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
            action: replace
            target_label: __metrics_path__
            replacement: /api/v1/namespaces/${1}/pods/${2}/proxy/metrics

And these are my queries:
CPU:
100 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", instance=~"$node"}[5m])) * 100)
Disk usage
sum by (instance) (node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype=~"ext4|xfs", instance=~"$node"} - node_filesystem_free_bytes{fstype=~"ext4|xfs", instance=~"$node"})
Available memory
sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~"$node"})
Memory usage
sum by (instance) (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~"$node"} - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~"$node"})
To solve I tried adding to prometheus-values.yaml:
prometheusSpec:
    retention: 7d
    storageSpec:
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 10Gi
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "4Gi"
        cpu: "2"
      limits:
        memory: "8Gi"
        cpu: "4"

but there is still the same problem.
In addition, I can write the helm configuration:
    resource "helm_release" "prometheus" {
    name = "prometheus"
    repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
    chart = "kube-prometheus"
    namespace = var.namespace

    set {
      name = "prometheus.service.type"
      value = "ClusterIP"
    }

    set {
      name = "prometheus.service.port"
      value = 9090
    }

    values = [
      file("${path.module}/files/prometheus-values.yaml")
    ]
}

resource "helm_release" "grafana" {
    name = "grafana"
    repository = "https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts"
    chart = "grafana"
    namespace = var.namespace

    set {
      name = "admiinUser"
      value = var.adminUser
    }

    set {
      name = "adminPassword"
      value = var.adminPassword
    }

    set {
      name    = "persistence.enabled"
      value   = true
    }

    set {
      name    = "persistence.size"
      value   = "10Gi"
    }

    set {
      name = "datasources.datasources\\.yaml.apiVersion"
      value = 1
    }

    set {
      name = "datasources.datasources\\.yaml.datasources[0].name"
      value = "Prometheus"
    }

    set {
      name = "datasources.datasources\\.yaml.datasources[0].type"
      value = "prometheus"
    }

    set {
      name = "datasources.datasources\\.yaml.datasources[0].url"
      value = "http://prometheus-operated.${var.namespace}.svc.cluster.local:9090"
    }

    set {
      name = "datasources.datasources\\.yaml.datasources[0].access"
      value = "proxy"
    }

}


Any chance that you recreate prometheus every day around that time, without preserving data?

No, I need data from previous days.

Have you checked logs from promehteus around that time, or logs from Grafana during the query?
